# When is There a Solution to "Pullback Equation" of Differential Forms

Tags: differential-geometry

All:

Let $f: M \to N$ be a smooth map between manifolds, and let $w$ be a $1$-form on $M$. Under what conditions is there a $1$-form $z$ defined on $N$ so that  $w=f^*z$, i.e., so that $w$ is the pullback of the form $z$ by the 
map $f$?

All I can think of is considering the respective cohomologies
of $M$, $N$, so that, e.g., if $H^1(N)=0$, then this would not be possible,
or maybe we can use the (contravariant)  map induced  by $f$ in cohomology,
but I cannot think of more general conditions.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I assume you mean $w = f^*z$ (instead of $z = f^*w$).

Comment: You always have pullbacks on differential forms. If $H^{1}(N) = 0$ that means there are no closed one forms which are not exact but there still are oodles of one-forms.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse ,just corrected it.

Comment: DBS: true, but I don't think there is always an injection, i.e., I don't think the induced map on cohomology is necessarily a surjection (nor an injection, but that's a different issue)

Comment: @DBS He's asking when one form is the pullback of another, not if forms can always be pulled back.

Comment: okay , I saw the correction afterwards.

Comment: If $M$ is a finite covering map in the sense of topology (or in more fancy language etale).

Comment: Dear @DBS, *étale* is not  fancy language for covering map, but  a much more general concept.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg In my undertanding* in the category of topological spaces or analytic spaces over $\mathbb{C}$ etale maps are (locally) covering maps. Of-course it is a huge generalization in algebraic geometry but I didn't mean that.                                                    *From Beauville's Complex Algebraic Surfaces.

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg Yes of course. I should have mentioned surjective finite \'{e}tale maps. My Bad!

Comment: When the cover is regular, it is necessary and sufficient that $w$ be invariant under the deck transformation group; that is $w=\phi^*\circ w$ for every deck transformation $\phi$.

Comment: But I'm not sure the map I'm working with is a covering map, tho it may be so locally, i.e., on non-critical points, i.e.,if x is not a critical point of f, then there may be an open set containing x so that f restricts to a covering map.